# Laravel 5.0 hasManyThrough column not found issue

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, has-many-through

I am five days into Laravel and after hours of watching Jeffrey Way I decided to delve into building an app to learn.

I am stuck at the point of working with tables in a hasManyThrough layout and identifying the columns that are the linkage between the tables. Eloquent is trying to use a column called 'id" as primary key that it cannot find. In my tables I am using the naming convention tablename_id like below. In my class function, I nominate the columns to use, but it fails with the error:

```
QueryException in Connection.php line 620:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'cable_installations.id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `cable_specifications`.*, `cable_installations`.`cable_specifications_id` from `cable_specifications` inner join `cable_installations` on `cable_installations`.`id` = `cable_specifications`.`cable_installations_id` where `cable_installations`.`cable_specifications_id` is null)
```

I am trying to retrieve:

**A distinct list of cable specifications that are allowed with a selected cable_installation_method**

Thanks!

**TABLE 1: cable_specifications**

```
cable_specifications_id (REPEATS)
other_columns...
```

**TABLE 2: cable_installation_methods**

```
cable_installation_methods_id (UNIQUE)
other_columns...
```

**TABLE 3: cable_installations (PIVOT)**

```
cable_specifications_id (REPEATS)
cable_installation_methods_id (REPEATS)
```

My classes are:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

 class CableInstallationMethod extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cable_installation_methods';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function CableInstallation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CableInstallation');
    }

    public function CableSpecByInstall()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\CableSpecification', 'App\CableInstallation', 'cable_specifications_id', 'cable_installations_id');
    }

}
```

In my controller, I call this function per below:

```
public function VoltageDropLoad()
{
    $InstallationMethods = CableInstallationMethod::all();

    $CableSelected =  CableInstallationMethod::where("cable_installation_methods_id", 1)->first();

    $CableTypes = $CableSelected->CableSpecByInstall()distinct()->get()->toJson();

    return view('pages.voltcalc', compact('InstallationMethods', 'CableTypes', 'CableTypes'));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your CableInstallationMethod class, you may have missed defining the primary key field for your models:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class CableInstallationMethod extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'cable_installation_methods';

    /* Need to define $primaryKey column here, normally defaults to 'id' */
    protected $primaryKey = 'cable_installation_methods_id';

    protected $fillable = [];

    public function CableInstallation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('CableInstallation');
    }

    public function CableSpecByInstall()
    {
       return $this->hasManyThrough('App\CableSpecification', 'App\CableInstallation', 'cable_specifications_id', 'cable_installations_id');
    }

}
```

With the primary key set you can also take advantage of using Model::find($id) instead of using Model:where(...)->first()

```
public function VoltageDropLoad()
{
    $InstallationMethods = CableInstallationMethod::all();

    $CableSelected = CableInstallationMethod::find(1);

    $CableTypes = $CableSelected->CableSpecByInstall()->distinct()->get()->toJson();

    return view('pages.voltcalc', compact('InstallationMethods', 'CableTypes', 'CableTypes'));
}
```